# How can I apply multithreading to the backpropagation neural network training?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

For my university project I am creating a neural network that can classify the likelihood that a credit card transaction is fraudulent or not.  I am training with backpropagation.  I am writing this in Java.  I would like to apply multithreading, because my computer is a quad-core i7.  It bugs me to spend hours training and see most of my cores idle.

But how would I apply multithreading to backpropagation?  Backprop works by adjusting the errors backwards through the network.  One layer must be done before the other can continue.  Is there any way that I can modify my program to do multicore backdrop?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all don't use backpropagation.  There are many other options out there.  I would suggest trying RPROP (resilient propagation). It won't be that big of modification to your backpropagation algorithm. You do not need to specify learning rate or momentum.  Its really almost as if you have an individual, variable, learning rate for every connection in the neural network.

As to applying multithreading to backpropagation.  I just wrote an article on this topic.

http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/mprop/compare.html

Basically I create a number of threads and divide up the training data so each thread has a near equal amount. I am calculating the gradients in each thread and they are summed in a reduce step. How the gradients are applied to the weights depends on the propagation training algorithm used, but the weight update is done in a critical section.

When you have considerably more training samples than weights the code spends much more time in the multi-threaded gradient calculation than the critical section weight update.

I provide some of the performance results at the above link.  It does really speed things up!

Comment: how do you merge the weights? What 'merge' means here, you add them all ?

Comment: Weights are not merged.  I am calculating the gradients in each thread and they are summed in a reduce step. How the gradients are applied to the weights depends on the propagation training algorithm used, but the weight update is done in a critical section. When you have considerably more training samples than weights the code spends much more time in the multi-threaded gradient calculation than the critical section weight update.

Comment: Your link serves a "Page not found".

Comment: the critical section is a real sticking point for me, i can make the gradient calculation for a batch very fast indeed, but an exorbitant amount of time is spent calculating and applying the updates.

Comment: nvm improved it by refactoring my code to move everything i can outside of the critical section. also there was overhead in loading my training examples before each batch which i was able to optimise.

Answer (score 0):

For using more CPU cores with Java you can just try more options for JVM without changing the code:

- -server
- -d64
- -XX:-UseParallelGC

and other options at http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp

Comment: Those options can speed-up the execution, but they will not make your algorithm parallel... If you want to use several cores to execute an algorithm, you will have to modify it.

Comment: Yes. Obviously. This options are just minimally required ones when you try anything parallel in Java.