# Multithreaded backpropagation

Tags: multithreading, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, gpgpu, backpropagation

I have written a back propagation class in VB.NET -it works well- and I'm using it in a C# artificial intelligence project.

But I have a AMD Phenom X3 at home and a Intel i5 at school. and my neural network is not multi-threaded.

How to convert that back propagation class to a multithreaded algorithm? or how to use GPGPU programming in it? or should I use any third party libraries that have a multithreaded back propagation neural network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JeffHeaton has recommend that you use resilient propagation (RPROP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830350/how-can-i-apply-multithreading-to-the-backpropagation-neural-network-training/1830355#1830355) instead of backpropagation. There are examples on how to do multithreaded RPROP (MPROP):

- [Article on C# multithreaded backpropagation](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/mprop/compare.html) (from Jeff heaton)
- [Chapter 7.2.1- "Propagation and Multithreading" (p.94 of Introduction to Encog 2.5 for C#)](http://www.scribd.com/doc/61710344/76/Using-Backpropagation)

It's a difficult to discuss all of the details here, so I would recommend that you either read that article and take a look at the relevant chapters of the book I referenced. This, of course, is assuming you're familiar with concurrent programming.

### Update:

> Resilient propagation will typically outperform backpropagation by a
>   considerable factor. Additionally, RPROP has no parameters that must
>   be set. Backpropagation requires that a learning rate and momentum
>   value be specified. Finding an optimal learning rate and momentum
>   value for backpropagation can be difficult. This is not necessary with
>   resilient propagation.
>   (source: [Encog Machine Learning](http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Resilient_Propagation))

Comment: Can you tell me why RPROP is better than backpropagation?

Comment: I've updated my answer describing why RPROP is better, but you don't have to use RPROP. The multi-threading concepts will work just the same with backprop.

Comment: Thanks, Is that article says that I should do multithreading for the loops INSIDE the main loop (which one run of it means one cycle/epoch)? if this is correct, each epoch takes a just 50-200 milliseconds to complete. won't it causes an slower neural network cause of initializing new threads?

Comment: If my question is correct (in previous comment), I should use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751324/create-new-thread-how-much-time-is-needed

Comment: The answers to the question you referenced above are both going to solve your issue, but in short: you want to create a few threads and reuse them over and over again on the operations you want to run (i.e. training your neural network).

Comment: `ThreadPool` does that implicitly, so does the TPL (`Parallel.For`, `Parallel.ForEach`, etc.) or you can just create a number of threads yourself. If you're not familiar with concurrent programming, then I'd be careful when using it... there are **many** ways to get it wrong!

Comment: in a nutshell, RPROP is usually better than backprop because it only uses the magnitude (sign) of the gradient.  The sign of the gradient is a great indicator of what direction to adjust the weight, but a poor indicator of how far to move the weight.  backprop adjusts this by using one single learning rate multiplied by the gradient.  RPROP rather keeps a delta value for each weight that is ratcheted up or down based on the magnitude of the delta staying the same.  Its like having a learning rate for EVERY weight, a single rate for all weights as in backprop.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried implementing multiple threads for RPROP batch processing, but it seemed it was always slower than using a single thread. I've tried to implement separately at the loop level "#pragma omp parallel" and by calculating the errors, gradients and weights in separate threads. In my interpretation, it seems that the computing done in each thread is too small to outcome the computing done in switching the threads and synchronizing the results (mutex.) I'm wondering if I've done something wrong? My conclusion is that would be smarter to run RPROP single-threaded, while processing multiple neuronal networks at the same time in separate threads. Most of the implementations usually imply multiple interconnected NNs so that would make sense.