# Create new thread, how much time is needed?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a main loop, and there are some loops inside it.

I want to multithread the loops inside. (a complete cycle of main loop takes 50-200 milliseconds. the main loop has about 3-4 loops inside)

How much time is needed to create a new `Thread`?

What is the fastest way to create and destroy threads?

Comment: How independent are the jobs that the inner loops perform?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: the inner loops are doing something with arrays, So they are independent. but main array isn't independent.

Comment: The fact that you're asking how fast you can create and destroy threads is indicative that you're doing something wrong in the first place. It's like asking how fast you can hire and fire people. Instead, hire the staff you need and keep them busy.

Comment: @EricLippert: OK. How to do that?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See these [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) methods

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `ThreadPool`.
This allows you to reuse threads from a managed pool instead of creating and destroying new threads each time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have .NET 4 (VS 2010) at your disposal, look at the Task Parallel Library - specifically `Parallel.For()` and `Parallel.ForEach()` for threading your looping constructs.

Comment: Reactive Extensions for .NET 3.5 has a version of the TPL. Anything less than that and you'll need to go with SLaks' suggestion.

Comment: This is the answer of my question in previous comment : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/parallelextensions/thread/389a2bd2-39e5-4078-80ac-e606162c99be and http://msmvps.com/blogs/brunoboucard/archive/2010/04/09/parallel-programming-task-oriented-parallel-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx) and [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx)