# Multithreading for backpropagation algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

To speed up some neural network learning, I tried to do some multi-threading, since for a particular layer, the calculations for each neuron are independent from one another.

The original function I used is some basic backpropagation algorithm, for the evaluation of the deltas in the net :

δ = derivative * Σ (weight * previous δ)

```
void backpropagation (Autoencoder* AE)
{
   int i, j, k;
   for(i = AE->numLayer-2; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      for(j = 0; j < AE->layer[i].size; j++)
      {
         register double sum = 0.0;
         for(k = 0; k < AE->layer[i+1].size; k++)
         {
            sum += AE->layer[i+1].neuron[k].weight[j] * AE->layer[i+1].neuron[k].delta;
         }
         AE->layer[i].neuron[j].delta = AE->layer[i].neuron[j].derivative * sum;
      }
   }
}
```

Autoencoder being the structure containing the neural net. It worked fine enough, if a bit slow, and it seems like a good idea to try this function first.

The modified functions are the following :

```
void backpropagationmultithread (Autoencoder* AE, unsigned int ncore, pthread_t* pth)
{
   int i, j;
   unsigned int neuronpercore, extra;
   sem_t semaphore;
   argThread* args[ncore];
   for(i = AE->numLayer-2; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      neuronpercore = AE->layer[i].size / ncore;
      extra = neuronpercore + (AE->layer[i].size % ncore);
      sem_init(&semaphore, 0, -ncore);
      for(j = 0; j < ncore; j++)
      {
         args[j] = malloc(sizeof(argThread));
         args[j]->layer = i;
         args[j]->AE = AE;
         args[j]->sem = &semaphore;
         args[j]->startat = neuronpercore * j;
         args[j]->nneurons = (j!=ncore-1)?neuronpercore:extra;
         pthread_create(&pth[j], NULL, backpropagationthread, (void*)args[j]);
      }
      sem_wait(&semaphore);
      for(j = 0; j < ncore; j++)
      {
         pthread_cancel(pth[j]);
      }
   }
}
```

And the function for the new threads :

```
void* backpropagationthread (void* arg)
{
   argThread* args = (argThread*) arg;
   unsigned int j,k,layer = args->layer, start = args->startat, end = args->startat + args->nneurons;
   Autoencoder* AE = args->AE;
   for(j = start; j < end; j++)
   {
      register double sum = 0.0;
      for(k = 0; k < AE->layer[layer+1].size; k++)
      {
         sum += AE->layer[layer+1].neuron[k].weight[j] * AE->layer[layer+1].neuron[k].delta;
      }
      AE->layer[layer].neuron[j].delta = AE->layer[layer].neuron[j].derivative * sum;
   }
   sem_post(args->sem);
   free(arg);
   return NULL;
}
```

argThread is just a little structure that contains all the arguments to be passed to the thread, ncore the number of CPU cores. The idea was to split up each layer into a roughly equal number of neurons to be treated individually by each thread (the last one with all the extra neurons if they are not multiples).

The new function does work to some degree, and much faster, but after a certain threshold does not converge anymore, where the old function did, and I cannot find why its behaviour would change. Am I missing some neurons or weights?

Comment: Ok, I admit i spent years in Windows and only recently dove back into pthreads, but why are you sending a cancellation request to you thread handles rather than `pthread_join()`-ing them ?

Comment: I am not too sure on what to do with threads once they are done. I tried removing that part, but no change really.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a multi-threaded backpropagation algorithm for Encog some time ago. I wrote this in Java, but when I implemented it in C, I made use of OpenMP, rather than pthreads.  You can see my C implementation here.

https://github.com/encog/encog-c

I also wrote an article about my approach for performing backpropagation in multi-threaded. 
You can see my article here.

http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/mprop/compare.html

There are a few other questions about this on Stack Overflow, as well.  Most seem to reference my algorithm.

[Multithreaded backpropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749890/multithreaded-backpropagation)
[How can I apply multithreading to the backpropagation neural network training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830350/how-can-i-apply-multithreading-to-the-backpropagation-neural-network-training/1830355#1830355)